# JsonValue.Parse not returning correct results

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to parse a .Json file which can be found here - http://files.star-made.org/releasebuildindex.json with this snippet I found on this site -

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        dynamic result = JsonValue.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://files.star-made.org/releasebuildindex.json"));
        Console.WriteLine(result.builds.version);
```

With the current version of the file (changes every week or 2 with a game update), it should be returning the string "0.163", yet it currently returns "default", which after some messing around, is what it returns if that tag does not actually exist.

I have no knowledge of Json, and can not edit that file as I am not its creator, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

-James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds is an array. You get the version like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(results.builds[0].version);
```

To explore the structure of a json string you can use http://json2csharp.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic keyword is nice, but it is way better to have static code checking and auto-complete. To enable this you need to have POCO(Plain Old CLR(Common Language Runtime) Object).

Copy Json and <kbd>Paste special</kbd> -> <kbd>Paste as json classes</kbd> (you need at least [Visual studio 2012.2 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx)):

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public string indexfileversion { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Build[] builds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Build
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string build { get; set; }
        public string rawVersion { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can use :

```
var json = new WebClient()
   .DownloadString("http://files.star-made.org/releasebuildindex.json");
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);
Console.WriteLine(result.builds[0].version);
```